# Which device to use for developing auto layout design

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I am new to auto layout, I want to develop app which is compatible from iPhone 4s(3.5 inch) to iPhone 7plus(5.5 inch).
I have a form of several fields which i want to show without using scroll.
Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

[Image preview of both devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWK2e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You want your layout to look good on every device so I would suggest testing it on every device.

Comment: Yes, i will test on every device, but i want to know how can i design a form of multiple fields which can fit every screen? i have uploaded image as well of my form.

Comment: So first you should edit your question. And answering your question: It depends on what you want to achive f.e. I if content is too big to fit on screen use scrollView.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot K. Michał

Comment: Sure thing. If I helped please consider accepting an answer and plusing and ofc if you have any more questions feel free to ask them too!